# Как автоматически создать папку для изображений?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.x, django-admin

Есть 2 модели CPU и GalleryCPU (смотрите models.py ниже), они связаны между собой связью один ко многим. Сделал я это для того, чтобы появилась возможность добавлять несколько картинок. То есть я связал 2 модели связью один ко многим и добавил inline редактирование (смотрите скриншот ниже).

**models.py**

```
class CPU(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория')
    slug = models.SlugField()
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=CHOISE_MANUFACTURER, verbose_name='Производитель')
    series = models.ForeignKey(SeriesCPU, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Серия')
    socket = models.ForeignKey(Socket, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Сокет')
    model = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='Модель')
    core = models.ForeignKey(Core, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Ядро')
    count_core = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Количество ядер')
    count_stream = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Количество потоков')
    normal_frequency = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Тактовая частота')
    turbo_frequency = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Частота в режиме Turbo')
    unlocked_multiplier = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Разблокированный множитель')
    cash_size_L1 = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Объем кэша L1')
    cash_size_L2 = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Объем кэша L2')
    cash_size_L3 = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Объем кэша L3')
    integrated_graphics_core = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='нет',
                                                verbose_name='Интегрированное графическое ядро')
    frequency_graphics_core = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Частота')
    technologic_process = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Технологический процесс')
    heat_dissipation = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Тепловыделение')
    technology = models.ManyToManyField(TechnologyCPU, verbose_name='Технологии')
    CHOISE_TYPE_DELIVERY = (
        ('box', 'BOX'),
        ('oem', 'OEM'),
    )
    type_delievery = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CHOISE_TYPE_DELIVERY, verbose_name='Тип поставки')
    guarantee = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Гарантия')
    count = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Количество')
    price = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Цена')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Процессоры"
        verbose_name = 'Процессор'
        unique_together = ('series', 'model', 'type_delievery')


class GalleryCPU(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img\CPU', verbose_name='Изображение процессора')
    cpu = models.ForeignKey(CPU, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images',
                            verbose_name='Процессор')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Изображения процессоров"
        verbose_name = "Изображение процессора"
```

[image: Inline редактирование]
Мне хотелось бы, чтобы при добавлении картинок для определенного CPU создавалась папка с именем этого CPU и все картинки загружались в эту папку. Например я добавляю CPU с именем Ryzen 5 1600, и при добавлении картинок для этого CPU у меня создается папка с именем Ryzen 5 1600 и все картинки загружаются в эту папку.

Есть мысль сделать следующим образом в модели CPU есть поле slug, исходя из этого можно реализовать следующий метод:

```
def image_folder(instance, filename):
    filename = instance.slug + '.' + filename.split('.')[1]
    return "{0}/{1}".format(instance.slug, filename)
```

Метод выше автоматически создает папку с именем slug и загружает туда картинку. Однако он подойдет только тогда, когда и поле типа Slug, и типа ImageField находятся в одной модели, то есть модели CPU. Но повторюсь ещё раз, они у меня находятся в разных моделях, а сделано это для того, чтобы была возможность добавлять несколько картинок. Вопрос как автоматически создать папку для изображений СPU с названием этого CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Однако он подойдет только тогда, когда и поле типа Slug, и типа
>   ImageField находятся в одной модели

Нет, это не так. Ничто не мешает обратиться к связанной модели по внешнему ключу:

```
return "{0}/{1}".format(instance.cpu.slug, filename)
```

Comment: изменил метод ка вы сказали. В модели GalleryCPU, изменил upload_to `image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_folder, verbose_name='Изображение процессора')` . Теперь при добавлении картинок появляется ошибка 'GalleryCPU' object has no attribute 'slug'

Comment: @НеуловимыйДжо а строкой выше тоже поменяли?

Comment: @Sergey_Gornostaev поменял в методе строку с return которые вы изменили. В модели GalleryCPU, изменил  upload_to, на `upload_to=image_folder`

Comment: Спасибо, надо было еще здесь поменять `filename = instance.cpu.slug + '.' + filename.split('.')[1]`. Теперь все работает